# HAProxy ACL whitelist IPs CIDR notation

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, cidr

I have an HAProxy load balancer and I would like to allow access only to certain IPs. I know how to do this using the regular notation:

```
acl is_ip_allowed src 173.245.48.1
http-request deny if !is_ip_allowed
```

But when I use CIDR notation is not working

```
acl is_ip_allowed src 173.245.48.0/20
http-request deny if !is_ip_allowed
```

This should be possible if I got the [HAProxy documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html) correctly

> IPv4 addresses values can be specified either as plain addresses or
>   with a netmask appended, in which case the IPv4 address matches
>   whenever it is within the network. Plain addresses may also be
>   replaced with a resolvable host name, but this practice is generally
>   discouraged as it makes it more difficult to read and debug
>   configurations. If hostnames are used, you should at least ensure that
>   they are present in /etc/hosts so that the configuration does not
>   depend on any random DNS match at the moment the configuration is
>   parsed.

But unfortunately, it's not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with a colleague I found an answer.

```
http-request deny if !{ src 173.245.48.0/20 }
```

So, removing the ACL and adding the CIDR range in an IF condition works.